# iOS admob interstitial ads for cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, admob, interstitial

I'm looking for a way to implement admob interstitial ads for my cocos2d games. I've looked every where but looks like there's no tutorial to implement full page admob ads for cocos2d. Let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why there are no answers :( I have banner ads up and running but I'm not sure how to implement interstitial ads. Can anybody help me? Thanks.